# simple template engine help

Tags: php, variables, templates

I've build a simple templating engine for a friend, however i have a problem which i think is a simple one

the script looks for these values in a template

```
$find = array("{$body}", "{$page_title}");
```

and replaces them with some other values.

However because they look like php variables I'm getting all sorts of errors and them being undefined.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use single quotes instead of double quotes, then the variables won't be parsed:

```
$find = array('{$body}', '{$page_title}');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$find = array('{$body}', '{$page_title}');
```

The " will parse the variable using ' he variable will not be parsed.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I got it right but try to replay the double-quotes with single-quotes:

```
$find = array('{$body}', '{$page_title}');
```